# Find two graphs with the same score, but one is a tree and the other is not a tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

The question is pretty self-explanatory:
Find a tree and a non-tree which have the same graph score. (The score of the graph is a sequence of the degrees of the graph from smallest to the largest)

I am thinking about one thing:

A graph is a tree when it is cyclic and connected. So if I want to make a graph which is not a tree, I think I should use the acyclic property of the tree

Comment: Whats a graph score. Context for this question?

Comment: The score of the graph is a sequence of the degrees of the graph from smallest to the largest

Comment: What have you tried? Context for this question?

Comment: "A graph is a tree when it is cyclic and connected" is not correct, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found it. This is the second easiest solution.
The tree is:

```
                  O-O-O-O-O-O
```

with the score of $1,1,2,2,2,2$.

The non-tree is:

```
                     O-O-O 

                       O 
                      / \
                     O - O
```

for which the score is $1,1,2,2,2,2$.

The simplest is (thanks to Stinking Bishop):

Tree:

```
                    O-O-O-O-O
```

The other graph:

```
                       O-O

                        O
                       / \
                      O - O
```

Their score is $1,1,2,2,2$

Comment: That is a fine solution.

Comment: Once you realise that the graph which is not a tree (but has the same score as a tree) must be disconnected, this is pretty much the second simplest example one can find. (The simplest is when you remove the "middle" `O` from the chain on the top, with the score $1,1,2,2,2$)

Comment: Update: I got an A on the final exam!